# Setting up the Raspberry Pi for the second time and WiFi detection issues

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, connection, headless

1. I am a beginner. When I bought my Raspberry Pi 3B a week ago, I was told that they had already applied a set-up. I didn't know what it meant and I followed a tutorial to set-up the Pi for the second time and that is when I realized that they meant they uploaded the OS onto the SD card already. Should setting up the Pi for the second time be an issue? I'd like to mention that I formatted the SD card before I myself set the Pi up.
2. The green LED blinks very slowly, once in 90 seconds. Does this mean anything?
3. Advanced IP scanner can't detect my Pi, detects every other device. Here's what I did:

   i. I formatted the SD card

   ii. Used Win32 disk imager to burn the Raspbian_Stretch.img file for the OS and uploaded it to the SD card's boot section.

   iii.  Inserted the SD card into my Pi.

   iv. Connected the Pi to a power source using adapter.

What am I doing wrong? I am using a headless method and I'm trying to bring the Pi into the network wirelessly.

Comment: SD card's boot section? odd phrase ... when you look at the content of the SD card in your PC, what do you see? Also, when you boot the Pi, what do you see on the connected monitor/tv?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you attempted to install the OS, but you should follow https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md

NOTE You are STRONGLY advised to use `Etcher`.

It is preferable to setup initially with keyboard and monitor, however it can be done headlessly. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

NOTE If the Pi is the latest Pi 3B+ there is probably no option, other than Ethernet or direct connection because WiFi is disabled until wireless regulatory domain is set.

Comment: I've never had luck setting up a Raspberry Pi without a keyboard/monitor. That's why I have a small monitor around so I can set them up for use without them. But aren't we supposed to be able to put the wpa_supplicant file in the boot partician along with an empty file "ssh" and have it work? Mind you, it's never worked for me. I also completely agree about etcher.